# Systemd Python service not sending all output to syslog

Tags: systemd, python, syslog

I have a custom service and have explicitly called for all **stdout** & **stderr** to be sent to **syslog** in the config file, however only some of the output appears in both syslog and the journal (they are consistent).

I my desperation I have done the following in the service files:

```
StandardOutput=syslog+console
StandardError=syslog+console
```

The service is a python script and I write to **stdout** using the `print` statement. These items seem to be lost to the ether, while other command outputs write correctly both to **syslog** and **journald**. If I run the script interactively everything appears in **stdout** as expected.

What is lacking in my knowledge?

Comment: The answer is the same as at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68059/ , http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206224/ , and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164987/ .

Comment: @JdeBP Awesome! I don't feel too bad as the question titles wouldn't immediately lead me to it. However, any tips for better searching, or is this just experience talking?

Comment: Only experience of seeing the question before and [writing tools for working around such behaviour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249801/5132).  (-:

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JdeBP's comment was the correct solution:

[Systemd Python service not sending all output to syslog](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285419/systemd-python-service-not-sending-all-output-to-syslog#comment497256_285419)

The solution was to add the `-u` option to the interpreter to make standard streams send their output unbuffered.

Comment: For me adding -u wasn't a good option.  Another way to do it is to call
sys.stdout.flush()
whenever stdout needs to be written.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can also set PYTHONUNBUFFERED to a non-empty string which is equivalent to specifying the -u option in Python2 and Python3 (Source: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED)

Comment: you can set a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/python3 -u` on your python script, set exec permissions and call it directly from your .service