# systemd: process with fork() only shows logs after child exits

Tags: linux, systemd, process, fork, journalctl

I have a program that `fork()`s and exits. Its child remains running for about 50 seconds, while it prints out messages each 5 seconds. When I run from a terminal it runs as expected, the parent exits, then the child prints 10 messages and exits too. I then created a `systemd` service unit with only this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Program that forks
Documentation=https://program5.example.com

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/root/fork
```

Apparently `systemd` works as it shows the main process active until the child exits, but checking `journalctl` or even looking at the program with `systemctl status`, the child messages on the screen only shows up after the child exits and the process is dead. Why is that?

Comment: It's the buffering question yet again. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505146/, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285419 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164987 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68059 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206224 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164987 .

Comment: unfortunately my program was in C and none of the links you posted helped me as they were all for Python. At least I understood it had to do with POSIX way of doing things and and how the OS was delaying the clearing of buffers to stdout, so I found out this: https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/unix-buffering. I understood I had to clean the buffer myself with fflush(stdout) in my case.